# Spotlight crashes after two letters have been entered

Tags: spotlight

OS X 10.11 on an early 2015 MBP

I am trying to search for a document called Starfleet, but after entering the letters "ST", Spotlight crashes.

Relevant logs:

> 02/10/15 12:12:37,642 Spotlight[1566]: XPC connection was invalidated
>   02/10/15 12:12:37,824 spindump[769]: Got xpc error message in
>   libspindump client connection: Connection invalid 02/10/15
>   12:12:37,825 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.Spotlight[1566])
>   Service exited due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 02/10/15
>   12:12:37,845 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.ReportCrash[1723])
>   Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please
>   switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.ReportCrash 02/10/15
>   12:12:37,852 ReportCrash[1723]: platform_thread_get_unique_id matched
>   158875 02/10/15 12:12:37,852 ReportCrash[1723]: Activity ID for thread
>   0x26c9b - 0x73f7a 02/10/15 12:12:38,217 ReportCrash[1723]: Saved crash
>   report for Spotlight[1566] version 1.0 (972.9) to
>   /Users/user/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Spotlight_2015-10-02-121238_computer.crash

Report:

> Process:               Spotlight [1566] Path:
>   /System/Library/CoreServices/Spotlight.app/Contents/MacOS/Spotlight
>   Identifier:            com.apple.Spotlight Version:               1.0
>   (972.9) Build Info:            SpotlightUI-972009000000000~1 Code
>   Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:        ??? [1]
>   Responsible:           Spotlight [1566] User ID:               501
>
> Date/Time:             2015-10-02 12:12:37.852 +0200 OS Version:
>   Mac OS X 10.11 (15A284) Report Version:        11 Anonymous UUID:
>   BF4F07CD-F3A3-3FE4-A07E-30BF365DFB58
>
> Sleep/Wake UUID:       EED97237-AF4B-48E7-9073-0F30A512606F
>
> Time Awake Since Boot: 9100 seconds Time Since Wake:       7300
>   seconds
>
> System Integrity Protection: enabled
>
> Crashed Thread:        5  Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos.overcommit
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
>   KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000010c780000 Exception Note:
>   EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> VM Regions Near 0x10c780000:
>       mapped file            000000010c70e000-000000010c780000 [  456K] r--/r-x SM=ALI
>   --> 
>       CoreAnimation          000000010c7c6000-000000010c7dc000 [   88K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV
>
> [...]
>
> Thread 5 Crashed:: Dispatch queue:
>   com.apple.root.user-interactive-qos.overcommit 0
>   libsystem_platform.dylib          0x00007fff8df54f49
>   _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Haswell + 41 1   com.apple.DictionaryServices   0x00007fff928fc127
>   HeapAccessContext::getDataByID(unsigned long long, long, unsigned
>   char*) + 477 2   com.apple.DictionaryServices     0x00007fff928ff0bc
>   TrieAccessContext::getHeapData(unsigned long long, long*) + 226 3
>   com.apple.DictionaryServices      0x00007fff928fecf8
>   TrieAccessContext::getMatchDataCommon(long, unsigned char const**,
>   long*, bool, CFRange*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, long*) + 2062 4
>   com.apple.DictionaryServices      0x00007fff928fee75
>   TrieAccessContext::getMatchData(long, long, unsigned char*, CFRange**,
>   long*) + 73 5   com.apple.DictionaryServices      0x00007fff928fa210
>   IDXGetMatchData + 53 6   com.apple.DictionaryServices 
>     0x00007fff928efe2b
>   DCSIDXDictionary::searchByString_internal(__CFString const*, long,
>   long) + 793 7   com.apple.DictionaryServices      0x00007fff928ef917
>   DCSIDXDictionary::searchByString(__CFString const*, long, long) + 43 8
>   com.apple.DictionaryServices      0x00007fff928f3bcd
>   DCSCopyRecordsForSearchString + 147 9   com.apple.ParsecUI
>     0x00007fff8896cfdb -[SPKDictionaryQuery start] + 773 10 
>   com.apple.Spotlight           0x0000000107e6e076 0x107e40000 + 188534
>   11  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff942148ff
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12 12  libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff94209453 _dispatch_client_callout + 8 13  libdispatch.dylib 
>   0x00007fff9420d2e3 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1890 14 
>   libdispatch.dylib             0x00007fff9420cb48
>   _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91 15  libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8499e4f2 _pthread_wqthread + 1129 16 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x00007fff8499c375 start_wqthread + 13
>
> [...]    Logical CPU:     0 Error Code:      0x00000004 Trap Number:
>   14
>
> [...]
>
> VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=318.4M
>   resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=318.4M(100%) Writable
>   regions: Total=391.4M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%)
>   swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=391.4M(100%)
>
> ```
>                             VIRTUAL   REGION  REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced)
> ```
>
> ===========                     =======  =======  Accelerate.framework               128K        2  Activity Tracing                  2048K        2  CG
>   backing stores                   16K        2  CG image
>   52K        6  CG shared images                   208K        6 
>   CoreAnimation                     2172K       76  CoreUI image data
>   336K       11  CoreUI image file                  224K        5 
>   Dispatch continuations            8192K        2  Foundation
>   20K        3  Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        3  MALLOC
>   175.8M       39  MALLOC guard page                   32K        7  MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)          169.8M        2         reserved VM
>   address space (unallocated) Memory Tag 241                       8K
>   2  Memory Tag 242                      12K        2  OpenCL
>   8K        2  Process Corpse Info               2048K        2  STACK
>   GUARD                       56.1M       16  Stack
>   14.7M       18  VM_ALLOCATE                        736K       18 
>   __DATA                            35.2M      336 
>   __IMAGE                            528K        2 
>   __LINKEDIT                        88.0M        7 
>   __TEXT                           230.3M      344 
>   __UNICODE                          552K        2  mapped file                      616.6M       65  shared memory                     16.3M        8 
>   ===========                     =======  =======  TOTAL                              1.4G      962  TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.2G      962

Comment: I'm having 10/3/15 3:33:10.519 PM Spotlight[2882]: XPC connection was invalidated, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a number of frustrating days, I have finally found a solution to this problem. I reindexed the volume for Spotlight, and that solved it.

The procedure goes as follows:

1. From the Apple () menu, choose System Preferences.
2. Click Spotlight.
3. Click the Privacy tab.
4. Drag a folder or an entire volume (your hard
   drive) to the list. If prompted for confirmation, click OK.
5. Remove the item or volume you just added to the list by clicking it and
   then clicking the minus ("-") button.
6. Close Spotlight preferences.

Spotlight will re-index the contents of the folder or volume.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716

Comment: Not working for me.  I narrowed it down to one particular drive and no matter how many times I force it to re-index, as soon as it's complete, the problem comes back.

Answer (score 9):

The solution above did not work for me: problem still occurred when re-indexing was over.
I found a solution here:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8546951

You must uncheck the "Bookmarks & History" option in the Spotlight pane of System Preferences.
It fixed instantly the problem for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Comment: This worked for me as well on mac OS Sierra

Comment: 5 yrs after, in Ventura 10.13 this also worked for me.   The problem did not appear until today after months of using with this box checked.